# BaseX XML database coding

Tags: xml, dtd, basex

I'm trying to create a DTD but have hit a wall. I keep getting pretty much the same error regardless of what I change the type to. Where am I going wrong?

```
<!ELEMENT movies (movie+)>
<!ELEMENT movie EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST movie id CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT budget (#PCDATA)>
```

The error I am receiving is "Failed to parse XML file: file:///E:/tmdb_5000_movies.xml
error occured at line: 52, column:9
cause of error: The content of element type "movie" must match "EMPTY"."
   [This is the xml database its working off of.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Enp4e.png)

Comment: If your question includes example data please include it as text rather than an image. This allows others to reproduce the issue.

Comment: The reference to BaseX isn't really relevant. This is an issue with parsing XML against a DTD.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared the element movie as EMPTY and the picture of your data includes child elements of movie. So, as the error says, your movie element isn't empty.